Проблемы с голосовым ассистентом неправильная работа
У меня проблемы с голосовым ассистентом, по типу Сири. Для того, чтобы выполнилась команда, нужно сначала назвать его имя, и сразу же назвать команду.
Мне же нужно, чтобы после называния его имени, он еще некоторое время ждал команды, а не запускал код заново. Можете ли помочь и как это решить? Прилагаю все файлы.
def va_respond(voice: str):
    print(voice)
    if voice.startswith(config.VA_ALIAS):
        # обращаются к ассистенту
        cmd = recognize_cmd(filter_cmd(voice))

        if cmd['cmd'] not in config.VA_CMD_LIST.keys():
            winsound.PlaySound('Yessir', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
        else:
            execute_cmd(cmd['cmd'])
def filter_cmd(raw_voice: str):
    cmd = raw_voice

    for x in config.VA_ALIAS:
        cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

    for x in config.VA_TBR:
        cmd = cmd.replace(x, "").strip()

    return cmd

# распознавание слов
def recognize_cmd(cmd: str):
    rc = {'cmd': '', 'percent': 0}
    for c, v in config.VA_CMD_LIST.items():

        for x in v:
            vrt = fuzz.ratio(cmd, x)
            if vrt > rc['percent']:
                rc['cmd'] = c
                rc['percent'] = vrt

    return rc


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос
